# How to change this regular expression to only match urls?

Tags: regex

I want to check for matches on strings that contain urls, like:

```
http://www.something.com

www.something.com

something.com
```

I have this regular expression (.Net style) to match urls:

```
((http|ftp|https|www)://)?(\w+?\.\w+)+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?
```

It works for above 3 urls which it should, but unfortunately it also matches this:

```
35.000
```

How can I fix the regular expression, so that it will not match 35.000?

Comment: Just filter out the matches that do not contain a letter, it should be easy if you are extracting texts in .NET.

Comment: As a sidenote you can change `(http|ftp|https|www)` to `(https?|ftp|www)` and your long list doesn't need to escape every letter and you can use `\w` instead of `a-zA-Z0-9_`, thus using `[\w~!@#$%^&*()=+\\\/?.:;',-]` instead.

Comment: url syntax is very complicated. Trying to do all the job with a single pattern isn't a good idea for two reasons:1) if you write the ultimate pattern that handle all possible cases, it will be unreadable and slow. 2) if you write a simple pattern, you will miss urls and you will match substrings that are not urls. Conclusion, choose a compromise: a simple, very lenient pattern + a build-in url checker to filter the results.

Comment: As an aside, the `www` branch in your pattern will never match `www.brinch.org` but will match `www://brinch.org`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really handy regex that matches URLs and places the protocol, host, path, query, and fragment into groups 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 respectively. Also it matches both IP adresses and hostnames in the host part. And everything but the host is optional.

```
(?:(https?|ftp)://)?(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}|(?:\w+\.)*[a-z]+)(/[^?#\s]*)(\?[^#\s]*)?(#[^\s]*)?
```

As you can see, it's *very* lenient. It just checks the overall structure without actually validating the parts of the URL (encoding and such). But it will match any correct URL so it should be good enough. Just escape the `/` slashes if using for Javascript and it should work fine.

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/0WehQU/3).

Comment: If I try with www.example.com, it doesn't match.